# Go To Position of Visual Cell on QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget in PyQT5 and I need to go to a specific visual position of the table.

How could I do it?

When I say visual I mean to give the row and column,then see on the table the given row and column visually

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say go to a position in the table?

Comment: Say i want to see row 20 and column 20,then the table widget must show that position visually

Comment: Let's see if I understand you, since the table has many elements only some items are visible, then you want me to give a row and column this item is visible by moving the scrollbars. I am right?

Comment: yes, that is what i want

Comment: ¿QTableWidget or QTableView?

Comment: It is a QTableWidget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the [`scrollToItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#scrollToItem) method, in the next part I show an example:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.rbox = QSpinBox(self)
        self.cbox = QSpinBox(self)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.rbox)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.cbox)
        vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)

        nrows = 50
        ncols = 30
        self.rbox.setMaximum(nrows-1)
        self.cbox.setMaximum(ncols-1)

        self.table = QTableWidget(nrows, ncols, self)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.table)
        for r in range(nrows):
            for c in range(nrows):
                it = QTableWidgetItem("{}-{}".format(r, c))
                self.table.setItem(r, c, it)

        self.rbox.valueChanged.connect(self.moveToItem)
        self.cbox.valueChanged.connect(self.moveToItem)

    def moveToItem(self):
        it = self.table.item(self.rbox.value(), self.cbox.value())
        self.table.scrollToItem(it)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```